# JQuery, jssha, and SHA512 - How To Call Function

Tags: jquery

I've been using SHA256 successfully and for an Admin section of a site I wanted to use SHA512.
I'm using the js from http://sourceforge.net/projects/jssha/files/

The only catch is a can't seem to call the function.
with sha256 I just do the following:

```
 SHA256('data');
```

But when I try the same with sha512 the script just stops at that point - doesn't work - eg:

```
 SHA512('data');
```

Also I can see the SHA256() function in the original code but not the SHA512 function... is there a trick to using this code? Another source I should use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    var shaObj = new jsSHA("This is a Test", "ASCII");
    var hash = shaObj.getHash("SHA-512", "HEX");
```

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the project on Sourceforge, there seems to be a separate sha512 file. http://sourceforge.net/projects/jssha/

edit: This works in console after loading sha512.js

```
var jsSha = new jsSHA("string to hash");
var hash = jsSha.getHash("SHA-512", "HEX");
```

Comment: yes I downloaded that file... I just need to know how to call the function... eg: how do I pass a string to get it hashed?

Answer (score 0):

Referenced from https://github.com/Caligatio/jsSHA/blob/master/README.md

```
var shaObj = new jsSHA("SHA-512", "TEXT");
shaObj.update("This is a test");
var hash = shaObj.getHash("HEX");
```