# where do I get jquery plugin SHA512

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, sha512

i googling no result ? can anyone help me ?

may be can build simple jquery plugin with sha512 ?


i search simple tool enycrypt jquery with sha512 
example
$.sha512Hex("test123"); 
can result "daef4953b9783365cad6615223720506cc46c5167cd16ab500fa597aa08ff964eb24fb19687f34d7665f778fcb6c5358fc0a5b81e1662cf90f73a2671c53f991"

Answer (score 1):

Looking for this?
http://sourceforge.net/projects/jssha/files/

SO Question: [JQuery, jssha, and SHA512 - How To Call Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544159/jquery-jssha-and-sha512-how-to-call-function)

Comment: dont unterstand that comment. can you clarify please? do you want to build a jquery plugin yourself or are you searching for a jquery plugin?